# Object (1) occurs when adding new details in admin panel

Tags: django

When i add new data, it will come up with object (1). If i go in the table with the many to one relation, it will not show the ID and instead show the "object (1). I have tried changing the field sets however this does not work. When i go to make a "UserAdmin" it will treat it like it a user being added.

[image: Images]

[image: Images]

**Admin.py**

```
from lib2to3.pgen2.token import OP
from statistics import mode

from attr import field
from .forms import createUserForm
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .models import Account, sni, Question, Option


class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('userID', 'is_staff', 'is_admin')
    search_fields = ['userID']
    readonly_fields = ()

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('userID','name','password1','password2','dateOfBirth','homeAddress', 'is_staff', 'is_admin', 'sni'),
        }),
    )

    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()
    ordering = ('userID',)



admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
admin.site.register(sni)
admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(Option)
```

**Model.py**

```
from asyncio import FastChildWatcher
import email
from pyexpat import model
from xxlimited import Null
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class userCouncil(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, userID, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email is required")
        user = self.model(userID = self.normalize_email(userID))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, userID, password):
        user = self.model(userID = self.normalize_email(userID))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
             

class sni(models.Model):
    SNI = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
    Used = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    password = None
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'SNI'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.SNI

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    userID = models.EmailField(primary_key= True ,max_length=256, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField(max_length=8, null=True)
    homeAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sni = models.OneToOneField(sni, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'userID'

    objects = userCouncil()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userID


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

class Question(models.Model):
    QuestionsID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    QuestionText = models.CharField(max_length=256, null = True)

class Option(models.Model):
    OptionID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    OptionText = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    QuestionsID = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Question` model needs a `def __str__(self)` function like your `Account` model. If you want to represent it with question ID it should look like this:

```py
def __str__(self):
   return self.QuestionsID
```

I don't remember if it will give an error because of it being other data type than string, in that case just cast it to string

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Is there another object then calling UserAdmin in the admin class I can use?

Comment: Could you say a little bit more? I don't understand the question

Comment: For example, in my admin class, I have used "UserAdmin" for AccountAdmin. When using this, django think i am making a user account therefore making me declare a username. I instead just want to change the layout. For example , I want the QuestionID and questionText to be both shown

Comment: For each model you can define what values to show in admin page by using ```@admin.register``` [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.register), defining a class and giving the ```list_display``` tuple of values you want to show(somewhat simillar to what you have done with AccountAdmin)